# Do Mersenne numbers occur in fields of mathematics other than Number Theory?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, soft-question

> Do Mersenne numbers turn out to be interesting in other fields of mathematics besides Number Theory?

In other words, are the primes occuring in the sequence
$$M_n=2^n-1$$
or the recursive realtion
$$M(n+1)=2\times M(n)+1$$
useful in other fields of mathematics to solve problems or appear in the definition of other important functions?

I apologize in advance for any mistakes in my English, I hope that the translator did a good job :).

Comment: They're great for making really bad RSA keys.

Comment: [see this Wikipedia page...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Mersenne_numbers_in_nature_and_elsewhere)

Comment: What do you mean? Using two mersenne numbers in the RSA algorithm generates weak keys?

Comment: @Coffee_Table :thanks but the section "Mersenne numbers in nature and elsewhere" is not very rich, for that I asked here.

Comment: Well, in my opinion, number theory has an importance among all fields of mathematics, so one important topic in number theory is certiainly of some importance in other fields. But notice that this saying is non-sense, so just have a look, and not treat it too seriously. :D

Comment: Well, i'm not taking this too seriously, i was just curious, if Meresenne numbers had other intresting properties not linked with prime numbers.

Comment: A generalization is the "repunits": Mersenne numbers are numbers of the form "111...1" in base 2; the analoguous exists for other bases. Let *b* be another base then ${ b^n - 1 \over b - 1}$ gives numbers, which are repunits in the digitrepresentation of that number system. So search for keywords "repunits" and also "cyclotomic polynomials" to find possibly more interesting stuff ...

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), "The Mersenne twister is a pseudo random number generator.... It provides for fast generation of very high-quality pseudorandom numbers, having been designed specifically to rectify many of the flaws found in older algorithms. Its name derives from the fact that period length is chosen to be a Mersenne prime."